# Does Blazor Use Virtual DOM or Incremental DOM?

Tags: blazor, virtual-dom

What does Blazor use to update the DOM. Is it Virtual DOM or Incremental DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses its own Render-tree, which is a Virtual DOM like the one in Vue and React.

Answer (score 3):

According to Blazor University, Blazor uses both a Virtual DOM and an Incremental DOM. See [this page](https://blazor-university.com/components/render-trees/) for more information.